# Red shifting galaxies

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, redshift, cosmological-inflation, observable-universe, deep-sky-observing

I am an amateur astronomer please correct if any of my understandings are wrong. We all know that from the Hubble's ultra deep field image the most distant galaxies which were created shortly after big bang looked to be red shifted. This is because of the process of expansion of the universe these lights are reached its highest visible wavelength. So in near future (in terms of astronomy) the galaxies which appears to be normal today become red shifted?  and those are already appeared as red shifted become invisible? If it become invisible still can we see it through infrared telescopes right?

Comment: By near future, you mean billions of years? If so, yes, you are correct. But you still have to be dealing with galaxies in the "Hubble flow" - not part of our local group.

Comment: Rob Jeffries' comment here is more useful than the accepted answer, which has inaccuracies and is in part misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an [open model of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe#Open_universe) and a long enough timeline galaxies which appear "normal" today would become more red shifted over the course of observation.  I put normal in quotes because there are no galaxies which are relatively static to ours.  Any galaxy which has movement will have some "shift" to them, and all galaxies [are moving away from us](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/cosmo/lectures/lec14.html).

It is possible that eventually the light from them could move into the infrared and even the microwave in extreme cases.

Comment: Galaxies in the local Universe are *not* all moving away from us. They have peculiar velocities larger than their cosmological recession velocities. A famous counterexample is the Andromeda Galaxy / M31 which is moving towards us and due to collide with the Milky Way in about 2 billion years.

Comment: I suspect that there are galaxies near enough that tjeir cosmological redshift is negligible yet far enough that it will not stay this way.